# Roll back in batch processing

Tags: mule, batch-processing, rollback, mule-component

While reading the mule docs batch processing, I read there are 3 ways to handle failures during batch processing. But while I am processing 100 records and the 4th record fails then I want to roll back the whole batch instead of continuing from the 5th record onwards. Is there a way we can roll back all the 3 records?

Answer (score 0):

Need to set Max Failed Record as '0'

```
<batch:job name="accesspayloadBatch" max-failed-records="0">
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Batch_Step"/>
    </batch:process-records>
</batch:job>
```

If you set it as`-1` it keep progress the record and ignore the failure. Perhaps set as `0`. It stop there itself and don't progress the 4th record. If you are using DB to insert record make as Transactional to revert it back.

Also refer this url: [Error handling in Mule Salesforce Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910322/error-handling-in-mule-salesforce-batch/37912307#37912307)