# Mule ESB Large File Handling

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have some scenario where I need to handle very large file like with file size as 20 GB or more. How I can handle these file in Anypoint Studio. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: By default files are streams. So you should not have a problem. It seems that you have issue when you try to read entire file into memory like Object to String. Don't do this and it will be fine. Or describe where you have issue and, again, avoid loading object to the memory.

Comment: Have you had any actual problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to large files, use `Batch` in Mule is the best option. This component handles large file and processes them faster.
Please find the details in below URLs:

- [Error handling in Mule Salesforce Batch - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37910322/error-handling-in-mule-salesforce-batch/37912307#37912307)

Edit: Removed the old URL as it is not exist anymore.

- In Mule4 Use this link for batch component reference [https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-processing-concept#:~:text=The%20components%20are%20the%20Batch,data%20sets%20while%20providing%20reliability](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-processing-concept#:%7E:text=The%20components%20are%20the%20Batch,data%20sets%20while%20providing%20reliability).

Comment: Most of these links are now dead making this answer almost useless w/o further explanation

Comment: @blurfus Thanks for the notification. Updated to current URL.

Comment: it's still beneficial to rely less on the external link and make the answer self-sufficient.  Please read [answer] for tips on how to improve this answer

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use Batch to read such big file. but if you can't then as as it is a file stream don't load the complete file in mememory, work with the file stream reader.